# Program : Mono Develop Unity - If Statment Issue

Tags: unity-game-engine, monodevelop, unityscript

For some reason everything after my second if statement does not work. When I remove that if statement ie.( if Texture == blue ) the if statement bellow runs, which is what I need it to do. But I need it to due that when the Texture is blue. does anyone know a solution to this problem? Its driving me nuts. By the way, There are no compilation errors or anything. Its a straight logic problem I think.

```
var blue : Texture;
function OnCollisionEnter(col : Collision){


if(col.collider.name == "Brick3"){
Destroy(col.gameObject);
score += 10;
guiScore.text= "Score: " + score;
renderer.material.mainTexture = blue;
}

if(Texture == blue)
{
if(col.collider.name == "Brick2")
{
Destroy(col.gameObject);
score += 10;
guiScore.text= "Score: " + score;
print("collided with brick");
}
}
}
```

Comment: What exactly are you comparing in `Texture == blue`? I can see where you declared `blue` and how you're using it, but `Texture` doesn't look like a variable... did you mean to compare `if(renderer.material.mainTexture == blue)`?

Comment: Steven is right. Protip, use Debug.Log to print things to the console - a single "Debug.Log(Texture == blue)" will tell you that the statement is false. This is basic debugging practice, if you can learn to understand your programs you will learn and work much more efficiently in the future.

Answer (score 0):

Compare the String with `equals()` method not with `==` operator

```
if(col.collider.name.equals("Brick3"))
```

Comment: Unity uses the .Net String class, so comparing strings with == is actually perfectly valid.